# Как отправить сообщение tg боту не асинхронным методом aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, aiogram

Пишу я бота в телеграм, который должен по расписанию отправлять всем своим юзерам конкретное сообщение. Всё бы хорошо, но способов сделать это с помощью aiogram я не нашёл, но нашёл библиотеку schedule, которая позволяет с заданными промежутками времени выполнять нужную функцию. Логику написал, поток отдельный создал, чтобы не мешало основной деятельности бота, но вот беда: чтобы по расписанию отправить сообщение, мне нужно использовать `await bot.send_message(...)`. Без await не работает, если ставить await, то нужно функцию обёртку делать асинхронной, но так как эта функцию передаётся в неасинхронную библиотеку, то и это не вариант. Подскажите, как можно отправить сообщение от бота иначе?

```
def schedule_checker():#с заданной sleep-периодичностью проверяет дату
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()#относиться к библиотеке
        sleep(1)

async def function_to_run():#функция передаёься в библиотеку для выполнения по расписанию
    db = SQLighter('sqlite_db.db')
    chat_ids = []
    for i in range(1, int(db.how_many_users()) + 1):
        this_id = db.get_tg_id(i)
        chat_ids.append(this_id)

    for chat_id in chat_ids:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=int(chat_id), text="This is a message to send.")
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every().tuesday.at("18:15").do(function_to_run)#относиться к библиотеке
    Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()#поток
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Как awaitить без awaitа я так и не понял, но проблему решил обычный get запрос `request = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{config.tg_bot.token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text=Не забудь скинуть чек, я его очень жду"`

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `await fu()` можно использовать `asyncio.create_task(fu())`. Такой таск выполнится после завершения функции, его вызвавшей.

И в Вашем случе schedule_checker можно вместо треда закинуть в таск с asincio.sleep.

Comment: посмотри https://stackoverflow.com/a/51294509/2101808, может убрать шедуле

Comment: Попробовал, не подошло для библиотечки, а может я не вкурил, в общем решил всё элегантно и просто, не заморачиваясь, просто отправил get запрос для отправки сообщения по инструкции к документации к TgAPI, но всё равно спасибо)